# Js сформировать параметр

Tags: javascript, ajax

Как сформировать такой параметр 'status' : 1 в переменную get?
Сейчас **$_POST** выглядит так

- [page] => 1 [get] => status:1

  нужно
- [page] => 1 [status] => 1

```js
    var test_url = location.search.match(/\?(?:(status|category|user*))=(\d*)/);
          var get = (test_url == null) ? '' : test_url[1]+':'+test_url[2];
          $(".pagination").bootpag({
           total: 4,
           page: 1,
           maxVisible: 20 
          }).on("page", function(e, num){
           e.preventDefault();
           alert(get);
           $("#box").load("file.php", {'page':num,get});
         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    var test_url = location.search.match(/\?(?:(status|category|user*))=(\d*)/);
                let options = { page: null };
                if (test_url != null)
                    options[test_url[1]] = test_url[2];
                $(".pagination").bootpag({
           total: 4,
           page: 1,
            maxVisible: 20 
         }).on("page", function(e, num){
           e.preventDefault();
                  options.page = num;
              $("#box").load("file.php", options);
         });
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)